# Mixing eventual consistency systems and legacy ACID systems

Tags: locking, distributed-transactions, lock-free, acid, eventual-consistency

Are there any patterns for mixing eventual consistency systems with legacy ACID-systems?

I want to store data in some(at least two) legacy systems on the mainframe that need ACID-like transactions. Those mainframe-databases(Let us call them OldWorld) are running under the same transaction manager in the same process so the consistency of the mainframe-systems is no problem.

I have a transaction manager that can handle XA-Transactions with the mainframe-tm and the ACID-able relational database in the non-mainframe environment (let us call this NewWorld).
But I do not want to use the XA-Transaction because it often causes trouble with long running locks on the mainframe-side and in many cases i do not need all ACID-Features for both worlds. I always want a consistent mainframe(All Data in the OldWorld are consistent inside the OldWorld). The NewWorld System can handle inconsistent data(Inconsistency between New and Old) when it reads data from the mainframe-side. The operations that are used to store data at the OldWorld are easy and save “add-only operations” whom cannot fail functionally (it can fail technically, but this should always be a temporary failure).

Answer (score 0):

My idea to work around the need for a distributed transaction is that i update the data in the OldWorld asynchronously and use an event sourcing data layer(in the NewWorlds) to store the information what is needed to be done in the OldWorld, using “soft-transaction-id's“ to prevent double-submitting to the OldWorld. These “soft-transaction-id's” will be generated while storing the data to the event-sourcing-data-layer for a transaction that needs to be done in the OldWorld.

I don't have the change to add my „soft-transaction-id's“ to the OldWorld-Databases but i can add a new Database that can store a „Done“-State beside the „soft-transaction-id“ and make the update of this database part of the old-world-transactions. Then another async-process can read the state-information without any locking and update the NewWorld (ex. Update relational-model with data from the event sourcing store. And marking the soft-transaction-id as done(„global-consistent“)) The Update of the OldWorld will always check if the soft-transaction-id is always committed first.

As i read through my writings i get the feeling that it's like global transaction, just with less locking. The knowledge that my update to the OldWorld will functional succeed is essential, without that you need a manually merge process, which can handle the functional conflicts. The NewWorld systems needs the functionality to handle inconsistent global state. It can be done by reading the relational-database and mimic the OldSystem DataRequests by analysing the not yet committed ( into the OldWorld-Database) event-store. For all other transactions I need to use distributed transactions with their locking behavior.